# How to update schema without restarting service

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

My program uses apollo-server-koa as graphql service and I want to update schema dynamically. For example:
- When user uploads data to server, the schema also need to be updated but not restarting service.
I read schema transform and schema stitching but these don't meet my requirement.
Anyone can give me an advice.
Thank you so much!

Comment: In particular case, I want to update both a typedef and a resolver

Comment: Apollo doesn't support updating the schema dynamically. If you want to do that, you'd need to set up your own middleware, recreate the schema each request and call `graphql`'s `execute` function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with apollo-server-express@1.3.2. I haven't converted over to 2 yet, and I'm not doing koa, but it'd be roughly the same, I assume. If not, hopefully it at least helps.

```
const { graphqlExpress } = require('apollo-server-express')
let schema = loadRemoteSchemas() // this loads it on start-up

app.use(async (req, res) => {
  return {
    schema: await schema,
  }
}

app.use('refresh', async (req, res) => {
  // some middleware that does stuff and changes the `schema` pointer
})
```

Comment: I know this but my project use apollo server 2

Comment: But in your solution, i found it performance is not good because server have to rebuild schema for each request

Comment: It shouldn't. `loadRemoteSchemas()` only gets called on startup with it written this way. Since it's an already-resolve promise, it'll just use the pre-fetched value every time it calls `await schema`. If `loadRemoteSchemas()` were inside the middleware, it would end up rebuilding on every request.